# Error: More than one instance of overloaded function matches the argument list

Tags: c++, visual-studio, overloading

I'm working with the library OpenMesh, and they offer two functions edge(), which only differ in their constness. [Const edge()](http://www.openmesh.org/Documentation/OpenMesh-Doc-Latest/a00187.html#a467829611338d02ece614f07b05a46b0) vs [edge()](http://www.openmesh.org/Documentation/OpenMesh-Doc-Latest/a00187.html#a60d244dc6531e5b249e63e73736f0d00). Is there any way to specify to the compiler which function I want to use?

It seems like this should have been a different design decision from the library, but not sure that I can alter that, so if there's anything I can do to bypass it in the compiler...I'm using VS2013.

I realize that people have already asked questions about this error, but I haven't found anything helpful for this type of case.

Comment: Are you having a problem with the function that the compiler chooses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you situation is like this: you have a

```
class aclass
{
  edge_t edge(void) ;
  edge_t edge(void) const ;
} ;
```

The second version will be called if you have a const object, the non const otherwise. So if you have

```
const aclass x ;
aclass y ;

x.edge() ; // calls the second
y.edge() ; calls the first
const_cast<const aclass &>(y).edge() ; // calls the const (second)
```

The latter is a (relatively) safe way to cheat...

Comment: Actually, the functions have a parameter Edgehandle, which is causing the problem. You can see the signature for the functions at the link I provided. Const casting the parameter results in the same error.  Also, they're functions, not methods, so it isn't being called on an object.

Comment: Well, how do they have a const specifier, then? I guess you should look at the answer again, it's the *this that should be const to call the const version, not the parameter.

Comment: That's true. It doesn't make sense... @BarisDemiray